# How take screenshot of scrolling window in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screenshot

What is the easiest way in C# to take a screenshot of a complete scrolling Window?

I have sceen examples on here using a web browser, but in this case the window is a Windows desktop application.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved this by using Win API and taking multiple screenshots, scrolling between each then joining them together.

Comment: How did you scrolled? Like some event that after first scroll when that portion loads, then take screenshot, detect screenshot event and then scroll next?

Comment: This is an answer? Geez :/

Comment: You should add some code so that anyone having a similar problem would have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get windows to redirect a WM_PAINT to an offscreen buffer with [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145216%28VS.85%29.aspx) and WM_PRINTCLIENT. This is better than screenscraping because it makes sure that obscured parts of a window(behind other windows) is painted anyway. If your target window scrolls by scrolling a child window position, WM_PRINT should apply. Just maybe it also helps your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Just 3 lines of code is enough

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pnlOuter.Width, pnlOuter.Height);
pnlOuter.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnlOuter.Width, pnlOuter.Height));
b.Save("D:\\bitmapImage.jpg");
```

`pnlOuter` is a panel that contains all the controls to be shown in image with extended height to contain all the inner controls. The containing form may have scroll bars enabled.